# automate sqoop incremental using cloudera hadoop UI

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera, sqoop

Is there any way to automate the sqoop import using a column value other than timestamp. I tried to use one column(ID) in my table. But it didn't work. Below is the sample code and I'm using cloudera hadoop UI to automate. Issue is the last value is not updating automatically.

```
         import
         --connect
         jdbc:mysql://172.26.122.123:3306/books
         --username
         hadoop
         --password
         ********
         --incremental
         append
         --check-column
         id
         --last-value
         0
         --table
         authors
         --as-textfile
         --fields-terminated-by
         ","
         --null-string
         \0
         --null-non-string
         \0
         --target-dir
         /user/thilina_08838/source/test
         -m
         1
```

Below is the structure of mysql table
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name      | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

Answer (score 1):

You can easily automate this using a saved sqoop import job.

```
sqoop job --create jobname --import --connect
     jdbc:mysql://172.26.122.123:3306/books
     --username
     hadoop
     --password
     ********
     --incremental
     append
     --check-column
     id
     --last-value
     0
     --table
     authors
     --as-textfile
     --fields-terminated-by
     ","
     --null-string
     \0
     --null-non-string
     \0
     --target-dir
     /user/thilina_08838/source/test
     -m
     1
```

You can put a cron job or ETL workflow according to your incremental refresh frequency and call `sqoop --exec jobname` in that.

Please refer the below for more info.

[Sqoop saved job documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose_4)

Comment: How we can do it in the Cloudera hadoop oozie UI?

Comment: Which cloudera version are you using?